# How to add a countdown timer to my turtle program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game using turtle where the player has to click as many randomly distributed circles in a set amount of time, but I'm stumped on how to create a timer inside the game. Whenever I try to set the timer, it counts down before the game starts or counts down after 1 circle spawns. I want to have it count down as the game starts, and have the game end once the timer ends.

I'm also trying to create a score counter, but am I using circle.onclick wrong?

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random, randint
import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def score():
    num=0
    print("Score: ",num)

def my_circle(color):

    radius = randint(10, 50)

    circle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.showturtle()

    circle.onclick(lambda x, y, t=circle: t.hideturtle())
    circle.onclick(num=num+1)

    return radius, circle


screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("Speed Clicker")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = []

for _ in range(0, 20):

    for i in range(40):
        print(str(40-i)+" seconds remain")
        time.sleep(1)

    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))


screen.mainloop()
```

The last thing I'm curious about is if it's possible to have the timer and score printed ON the game, rather than on the Python Shell.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few alterations and this seems to work. I have put the score and the time left in the title bar of the game. Thanks

```
import turtle
from random import random, randint
import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

num=0
def increase_score():
    global num 
    num += 1

def my_circle(color):

    radius = randint(10, 50)

    circle = turtle.Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.showturtle()
    circle.onclick(lambda x,y,t=circle: (circle.hideturtle(), increase_score()))

    return radius, circle


screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("Speed Clicker")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = []

gameLength = 5
# Higher number means faster blocks
# 1-10
difficulty = 10
startTime = time.time()
while True:
    time.sleep(1/difficulty)

    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time.time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))
    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(num,int(round(gameLength - timeTaken,0))))

    if time.time() - startTime > gameLength: 
        break

screen.title('FINISHED! FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(num))

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. Thanks so much

Comment: @chankim great! Please mark as best answer and upvote if it solves your problem! Thanks!