# Displaying Timer on Turtle Game

Tags: python, time, turtle-graphics

Here is my code for a 30sec timer on my turtle game:

```
import time
starting_time = time.time()
time_limit = 30

while (time.time() - starting_time) < time_limit:
#Game logic here
```

My question is: How do I display a count down timer on the screen?

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742388/how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-my-turtle-program?

Comment: Not really, no, but let me review and I'll play around... thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the time library, I'd use turtle's own timer event to create a countdown timer:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Arial', 30, 'normal')

def countdown(time):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable click until countdown completes
    turtle.clear()

    if time > 0:
        turtle.write(time, align='center', font=FONT)
        screen.ontimer(lambda: countdown(time - 1), 1000)
    else:
        turtle.write("Click Screen", align='center', font=FONT)
        screen.onclick(lambda x, y: countdown(30))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.write("Click Screen", align='center', font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(lambda x, y: countdown(30))
screen.mainloop()
```

This will run independently of other action on the screen as long as you stay within the turtle event model.